# Preventing certain moves using ValueSelector results in ClassCastException

Tags: optimization, optaplanner

I have a `Lecture` class with a `startTime` planning variable and a fixed duration. I'm trying to filter out moves that causes the end time to go past 16:00.

I have written a selection filter:

```
public class LectureOutOfBoundsSelectionFilter
        implements SelectionFilter<Schedule, Lecture> {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<Schedule> sd, Lecture lecture) {
        return !lecture.isOutOfBounds();
    }
}
```

Which I configure as follows

```
<changeMoveSelector>
    <filterClass>package.PinnedTimeslotChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
    <valueSelector>
        <filterClass>packager.LectureOutOfBoundsSelectionFilter</filterClass>
    </valueSelector>
</changeMoveSelector>
```

But I'm getting a class cast exception related to a different planning variable in `Lecture`. I've tried adding `variableName="startTime"` but this triggers a different class cast exception.

Am I on the right track here, and how does the `variableName` attribute actually work?

Comment: Would you mind also pasting the two CCEs you're getting? The root cause will do.

Comment: With `variableName="startTime"` I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: class package.ImmutableTimeslot cannot be cast to class package.Lecture`.

Without `variableName` set, I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: class package.Room cannot be cast to class package.Lecture`. (`room` is another planning variable of `Lecture`).

I don't know if I can/should set `variableName` to `Lecture` somehow, but `Schedule` has a `List` of `Lecture` objects, so there's no variable name referring to individual lecture objects.

Comment: Could be a bug, not yet sure. Will have to look into it more.

Comment: So how does a value selection filter work? Is the move "proposed" (planning entity updated), and then my selector is called? And what moves is the selection filter associated with? Is it determined by the signature of the `accept` method? So, in my case, if a `changeMove` for example updates a `Lecture`, my selection filter will be invoked? If this is the case, how does the `variableName` come into play? Is it that if I specify `startTime`, the selection filter will only be invoked if a `changeMove` updates the `startTime` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off your additional comment, where you explain further:

> With `variableName="startTime"` I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: class package.ImmutableTimeslot cannot be cast to class package.Lecture`.  Without variableName set, I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: class package.Room cannot be cast to class package.Lecture`.

There is an explanation for this behavior, although it is not really very intuitive:

- When you put the filter on the value selector without a variable name, *both* variable types will reach the filter. In this case `ImmutableTimeslot` and `Room`. Since your filter expects a `Lecture`, either of the two throws the exception.
- When you specify the selector's variable name to be `startTime`, this no longer triggers the value selector on values of the `room` variable; therefore, you are getting an exception where `ImmutableTimeslot` doesn't match `Lecture`.

In both cases, the problem appears to be that your filter is expecting `Lecture` instances (the entities), but the solver is sending either `ImmutableTimeslot` or `Room` (values of the planning variables). This is arguably the correct behavior of a *value* selector (emphasis on the word "value").

The reason why I'm calling this "not really intuitive" comes in two parts:

- The same `SelectionFilter` interface is always required, regardless if applied to a move selector, an entity selector or a value selector. So, based on where you intend to use it, the generic type required is different and that is confusing. (A move, an entity or a value respectively.)
- In cases with multiple variables (such as yours) without specifying a `variableName` on the selector, the generic parameter needs to be `Object`, because that filter will be receiving both types of values and that is the only way to avoid the exception you are getting.

All in all, not the best design; it comes from 2012 and due to maintaining backwards compatibility and us actually discouraging the use of selection filters, it has survived unchanged until the present day.

Comment: Thanks @Lukáš Petrovický. This really answers all questions I had. Here's where I "came from": I want to restrict what values (`ImmutableTimeslot`) can be assigned to the `startTime` variable, but which values should be allowed, depends on the duration of the lecture (`lecture.startTime` + `lecture.duration` should not exceed end of day). Hence, I need access to the planning variable (the lecture) that the value is about to be assigned to. I realize after reading your answer that a `SelectionFilter` is not the way to go. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: There are different approaches for different situations. I'd start by limiting the value range - there are some values that are *guaranteed* to go over the end of day, don't generate them. For the values that possibly could be used, either rely on the solver to be smart enough to not use them too often, or use the lecture's properties to generate a different value range on-demand. (For that, the value range needs to be on the entity; this may bring some problems of its own. If that's the case, selection filters are probably your only approach, which is why they survive.)

Comment: Ack. Thanks again Lukáš! Great info.